# Access resource file from JSP

Tags: java, jsp, web-inf

I want to access xml files from java class, lying under web/resources folder..
i.e

---Web pages
|
|--Web-INF
|
|-resources
| |-data.xml
|
|-other jsps
---Source Folder
|-databean

I want to access data.xml from a class under databean package. Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`ServletContext#getResource()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) or [`#getResourceAsStream()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) to obtain resources which are available in the webcontent.

```
InputStream input = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/resources/data.xml");
```

You however [normally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) do that in a [Servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info), not a [JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info).

Comment: hello sir, i want it access in a java class. Not even in servlet. Can u help me over it?

Comment: Pass the `ServletContext` to it as constructor/method argument so that you can use it, or move the file to the classpath, so that you can use `getClass().getResourceAsStream(path)` instead.

Comment: What's the better and practical way?

Comment: Depends on who needs the file. If it are the Java classes, put in classpath. If it are the Servlets/JSP pages, put in webcontent. You apparently don't need it in Servlet/JSP at all, in contrary to what the question title suggests :)